# Long not giving the result I expect it to

Tags: c, sum, calculator, long-integer

I am using the below code to get a long int sum of 2 numbers.
I take the inputs as long ints and expecting a long int answer through printf but am getting the result as a negative number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long x;
    long y;      
    printf("enter x:\n");
    scanf("%ld", &x);
    printf("enter y:\n");
    scanf("%ld", &y);
    printf("%li\n", x + y);
}
```

Comment: What is your input? What is `sizeof(long)` on your system?

Comment: My input for both x and y are 2000000000, I am not sure about the size though

Comment: It is important. `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long));`

Comment: Please show exactly what output you're getting

Comment: getting 4 as the result for this printf command

Comment: Hi Chris, I am getting -294967296 as the result

Comment: Interesting. I get `4000000000`. Is `long` 32 or 64 bits on your platform?

Comment: If `sizeof(long) == 4` then it is 32-bits. The values it can store are `-2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647`. Consider `long long` instead or `int64_t`

Comment: Thanks, using long long worked for me however I am not sure how to use int64_t to do the same, I am trying to get some documentation on it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I make one small change to your code, I get your output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;      
    printf("enter x:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("enter y:\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("%i\n", x + y);
}
```

```
% ./a.out
enter x:
2000000000    
enter y:
2000000000
-294967296
```

This indicates that you're using a platform where `long` is 32-bits. To ensure you're using a 64-bit signed int, use `int64_t` rather than `long`.

We can use the `PRIi64` macro from the `inttypes.h` header to make sure we get the right format specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    int64_t x;
    int64_t y;      
    printf("enter x:\n");
    scanf("%" PRIi64, &x);
    printf("enter y:\n");
    scanf("%" PRIi64, &y);
    printf("%" PRIi64 "\n", x + y);
}
```

You should also get in the habit of checking the return value from `scanf` so that you can know when I/O has failed and address it immediately.

Comment: Thanks, using long long instead worked for me. however not sure how to get it done using int64_t as I have not used it before

Comment: `int64_t` is a type defined in `stdint.h`. Documentation [at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)

Comment: A closer match to OP's code would use `scanf("%" PRId64, &x);`